# saving common strings to a new text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

To get similar files among different text files I've used `ismember()`

```
file1 = {'DSC01605.bmp';'Hampi8.bmp';'DSC01633.bmp';...
 'DSC01198.bmp';'DSC01619.bmp'}

file2 = {'DSC01605.bmp';'Hampi8.bmp';'DSC01633.bmp'}

file3 = {'DSC01605.bmp';'Hampi8.bmp'}

matching12 = ismember(file1, file2)
matching13 = ismember(file1, file3)
matchesAll3 = matching12 & matching13

allMatchingStrings = file1(matchesAll3)
```

Now `allMatchingStrings` contains

```
'DSC01605.bmp'
'Hampi8.bmp'
```

How can i write these files to a new text file `all.txt`? Problem with my requirements is - suppose `allMatchingStrings` contains around 10 files, but i need only 5 out of those 10 files. I need to save 5 files to a new text file say `all.txt`. How can i do that?

Comment: new text file `all.txt` need to be overwrite for each time, i mean contents in `all.txt` should over-write old ones if some other files gets stored in `allMatchingStrings`

Comment: Can you explain this: *`allMatchingStrings` contains around 10 files, but i need only 5 out of those 10 files.*, please? How do you determine which names from `allMatchingStrings` to write to the file?

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't mention that, among 10 files it can be any 5 or those which are listed from top, i mean starting from 1st to 5th file.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to write them to disk is with the fprintf command.

```
fid = fopen('all.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', allMatchingStrings{:});
fclose(fid);
```

If you only wanted to write the first 2 filenames in `allMatchingStrings` then you could limit like this:

```
filenamesIWant = 1:2;
fid = fopen('all2.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', allMatchingStrings{filenamesIWant});
fclose(fid);
```

This works because the fprintf command repeats for each string you give it. The only trick is getting the curly brackets int he right place.

Comment: What does `1:2` indicates? if i want first 5 files, will `1:5` works?

Comment: This results in an error `??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`

`Error in ==> Fig5>search_Callback at 309`
`fprintf(fid, '%s\n', allMatchingStrings{filenamesIWant});`

`Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96`
        `feval(varargin{:});`

Comment: The above code appears to be correct. Your error message suggests that `allMatchingStrings` is not a cell array in the context of this function. Put a breakpoint right before the statement (add the line `keyboard` on a line by itself), then examine the variables. The error should be obvious.

Comment: @Chethan If you want to do the first five you would do 1:5. Like @Floris says, if looks like you don't have a cell array but if you run your original example  with `file1, file2, file3` then it should work.